# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘tipoNo’ {aka ‘struct tipoNo’} from type ‘tipoNo *’ {aka ‘struct tipoNo *’} arv = inserir(&arv, 5);

Tags: c, ponteiro, árvore-binária

Estou tentando implementar o método de inserção de uma árvore binária de pesquisa. Esse é a struct que estou usando

```
typedef struct tipoNo
{
  int chave;
  struct tipoNo *esq, *dir; //apontadores da esquerda e direita
} tipoNo;
```

e meu método de inserção é esse :

```
tipoNo* inserir(tipoNo *r, int chave)
{
  if (r != NULL)
  {
    if (chave > r->chave)
      r->dir = inserir(r->dir, chave);
    else
      r->esq = inserir(r->esq, chave);
  }
  else
  {
    r = (tipoNo *)malloc(sizeof(tipoNo));
    r->chave = chave;
    r->dir = NULL; r->esq = NULL;
  }

  return r;
}
```

Quando chamo o método de inserir na main eu recebo o erro de tipos incompatíveis

> "incompatible types when assigning to type ‘tipoNo’ {aka ‘struct
>   tipoNo’} from type ‘tipoNo *’ {aka ‘struct tipoNo *’}    arv =
>   inserir(&arv, 5);"

, sei que o arv precisa ser um ponteiro pra receber um ponteiro mas não consegui fazer isso pois quando fiz essa implementação criando a arv como *arv na main, obtive o mesmo erro

> "expected ‘tipoNo *’ {aka ‘struct tipoNo *’} but argument is of type
>   ‘tipoNo **’ {aka ‘struct tipoNo **’}  tipoNo* inserir(tipoNo *r, int
>   chave);"

```
  tipoNo arv;
  criar(&arv);

  arv = inserir(&arv, 5);
```

Se eu não ponho o arv para receber o retorno do método inserir, dá segfault e quando ponho, tenho esse erro. Eu sei que preciso que o arv receba o retorno do método inserir para que a árvore com que eu esteja trabalhando na main possua os valores 'inseridos' mas não consigo fazer com que o arv seja capaz de recebê-lo.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stackoverflow, se possível ajuste o título de sua pergunta. Coloque qual sua dúvida. Trechos de código no título não são bem vistos.

Comment: neste comando `arv = inserir(&arv, 5);` a variável `arv` é declarada como `tipoNo`, mas a função `inserir` é declarada como `tipoNo*`...você não pode fazer atribuição de um ponteiro para uma variável que não é ponteiro

Answer (score 2):

Como a sua estrutura possui membros do tipo dela mesma, você vai precisar de uma [`forward declaration`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) antes de sua definição completa, veja só:

```
typedef struct estruturaNo tipoNo; // forward declaration

struct estruturaNo
{
  int chave;
  tipoNo *esq;
  tipoNo *dir;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente não gosto de trabalhar com retorno quando estou usando árvore binária, listas... 
Vou te passar um link de um professor que me ajuda a trabalhar com isso: [Listas Lineares](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vugkpyq37vob2im/AAAZs8TaJVaspAfbCN5sVK48a/discreta?dl=0&preview=aula-upe-listas-lineares.pdf&subfolder_nav_tracking=1)

Para declarar estruturas eu gosto de usar:

```
typedef struct st_tipoNo
{
    int chave;
    tipoNo *esq;
    tipoNo *dir;
} t_tipoNo;
```

E para declarar:

```
t_tipoNo *arv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está atribuindo um ponteiro (retorno da funcao "inserir") para a variável "arv", que não é ponteiro.

Correção:

```
// tipoNo arv; // <------------- ERRO
tipoNo* arv = NULL;

// criar(&arv); // <------------ DESNECESSARIO

arv = inserir(&arv, 5);
```